# Extract decimal from start of string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string like `5.5kg` or `7.90gram` and I want to get `5.5` or `7.90` as a decimal value. How can I get such result in C# and one more thing that my string will always starts with decimal.

Here is my code that throws an error whenever it will encounter anything except a decimal.

```
string weight = attributeValue;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(weight))
{
    product.Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(attributeValue);
}
else
{
    product.Weight = 0.00m;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would create a regular expression matching the leading number part. This will partly depend on whether you will *always* have a decimal point, whether you want to allow commas for thousands separators, whether it will always use `.` as the decimal point, etc. It might look something like this though:

```
^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Then match that regular expression against your text, take the value of the match (if it's successful) and use `decimal.Parse` or `double.Parse` on that value:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?");
Match match = regex.Match(text);
if (match.Success)
{
    weight = decimal.Parse(match.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Note that for "natural" values such as mass, you *may* be better off with `double` than `decimal`. The latter is more appropriate for "artificial" values such as currency, which are naturally best expressed in decimal and have exact values. It depends on what you're doing though.

Comment: The current regex will only match floats/integers at the start of the string due to `^` anchor. To extract numbers from any location in the string, use `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`. Or `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yup, because I answered the question that was asked: "one more thing that my string will always starts with decimal".

Comment: Yes, sure, just the title does not imply that, I think it should be edited.

Answer (score 2):

here is a completely different approach

```
    string oldstr = "1.7meter";
        Char[] strarr = oldstr.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || Char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray();
        decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal( new string(strarr));
```

Answer (score 0):

> For your input format you can get decimal by this code

```
var weight =Decimal.Parse( Regex.Match(input_string, "[0-9]*\\.*[0-9]*").Value);
```

> if your input string is in different format then you have to change
>   the **regex pattern**.