# float to string with no decimal value in C#

Tags: c#, numbers, decimal

This is how I get previous greatest ID from my datasource and plus one to this value .

```
   string _fID = (float.Parse("." + DBContext.Employees.OrderByDescending(x =>   
    x.EmpID).FirstOrDefault().EmpID.ToString()) + .00001f).ToString("F5");
```

And I get `_fID = 0.00002`  .

But what I want is the string with no decimal value .
Eg. `_fID = 00002` .

What I've done is replacing like `_fID = _fID.Replace("0.","");` .
Is there any short way to make this stuff ? Thanks you all :)

**PS**

Data Type of EmpID is `nvarchar(5)` .

Comment: Why are you using the floating point number at all if you don't actually want decimal values? Why not just use integers and format with appropriate numbers of zeroes? And have you considered using `decimal` instead of `double`?

Comment: You can use more generic way of extracitng values using regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061550/extract-decimal-from-string

Comment: @JonSkeet , please show me some example . Thanks :)

Comment: No, please give more detailed requirements first. This is an odd question in terms of requirements, and I can just imagine people giving answers that you then say are inappropriate because of requirements which aren't in the question. Please edit your question to give more of the bigger picture. What's the data source? Why are you formatting it like this? Do you always want 5 digits? What led you to your current design?

Comment: Why are you using `float.Parse` to start with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you stop using floating point types at all. Just use integers, as that's basically what you've got. (It's a shame that your data type is textual when you're logically just using integers.)

```
string currentHighest = DBContext.Employees
                                 .Select(x => x.EmpID)
                                 .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                                 .FirstOrDefault();
// TODO: Handle currentHighest being null (empty table)
int nextId = (int.Parse(currentHighest) + 1).ToString("00000");
```