# Finding numbers and doubles in text line in Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I need to find numbers/double in text line fields and return its value. 
Text line could be something like this : "asdajkj asdk asdkj 10.1 asdasd" 
So i want back the value of 10.1 from this line.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061550/extract-decimal-from-string

Comment: if the input text like this: "abc 123 efg 456.78",what's the value you wanted?

Comment: @Paweld_00 maybe the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11061592/1257607) from Jon Skeet is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Regex to do that:

```
string input = "asdajkj asdk asdkj 10.1 asdasd";

string res = new string(input.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.').ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(res); // 10.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
string yourString = "asdajkj asdk asdkj 10.1 asdasd";
var resultString = Regex.Match(yourString, @"-?\d+(\.?\d+)?").Value;
```

For more:-

```
string yourString = "asdajkj asdk asdkj 10.1 asdasd";
string firstOccurance = Regex.Match(yourString, @"-?\d+(\.?\d+)?").Value;
Console.WriteLine(firstOccurance);

/* Multiple Occurance */
string yourString_2 = "asdajkj 10 asdk 23.26 asdkj 10.1 asdasd 15 ";
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(yourString_2, @"-?\d+(\.?\d+)?");
foreach (Match item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works great ;)

Comment: @Paweld_00 did you want only the first occurance?

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "sdajkj asdk asdkj 10.1 asdasd";

// Split on one or more non-digit characters.
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
```

Comment: from this case i would not have 10.1 in case just 10

Answer (score 0):

To get the first number from your string.

```
Regex.Match(yourString, @"(?<=^\D*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Value
```