# Extract double from any location inside string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract double from a string like this :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?");
Match match = regex.Match(mystring);
if (match.Success)
{
   double number = double.Parse(match.Value);
}
```

And my string is like this : "STR/STR: 1.25"

However Match.Success returns false. Why does it return false? Thanks.

Comment: remove the ^ and it should work ...

Comment: You've explicitly anchored the match to the start of the string, but your string *doesn't* start with a double...

Comment: And why not simply use `Double.Parse` or `TryParse` respectivly? Simply KISS.

Comment: May be you want a *different anchor*, `$` instead of `^`: `@"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$"` if you're looking for `double` at the *end* of the string (as in the example provided by you -  `"STR/STR: 1.25"`)

Comment: @HimBromBeere Because there's other text in the target string.

Comment: It is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061550/extract-decimal-from-string, I think. Jon Skeet did not explain it only matches at the start of the string.

Comment: Try: `[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Markus indicated, if you want it to match regardless of where the double is in the string, simply remove that ^ which indicates that it is checking the start of the string: `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`
(Note that this may result in more than one match.)

If you want it to match only when the string ends in the double, add a $ to the end: `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

Online regex validators are incredibly useful, and some will break down which each individual component does. It's a lot faster to test out a regex this way instead of recompiling repeatedly until you get it right.

[This is one of many.](https://regex101.com/)

EDIT: As Wiktor pointed out, this site doesn't actually validate .NET syntax regex. Therefore, it may not be suitable for certain types of regular expressions, but many common scenarios will be identical.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ does not support .NET regex syntax. Some .NET regular expressions can be tested there, but those using character clas subtraction or balanced constructs won't work. Also, PCRE conditional constructs behave a bit differently from .NET conditional expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code sure it will work

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

        string txt = "I got 93.86 percentage";

        string re1 = "(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1
        string re2 = "(\\.)";   // Any Single Character 1
        string re3 = "(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 2

        Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2 + re3, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(txt);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            String int1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String c1 = m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String int2 = m.Groups[3].ToString();
            double dblResult = Convert.ToDouble(int1 + c1 + int2);
        }
```